# Web browser back functionality not working

Tags: c#, list, url, browser

I have written a method for forward and backward navigation for my webbrowser. The aim is to store the visisted sites (urls) into a list called webHistory. I then attempt to loop through this string for my back and forward navigation. However its doesn't seem to work. I have checked and confirmed that the list is being populated. Here's my code.

My Web Browser Class

```
  public partial class WebBrowser : Form
{

    public string url;
    public string addressText;
    private homeForm homeForm;
    private List <string> urlList = new List <string> ();
    List<String> webHistory;
    int webHistory_Index;
    bool checkHistory;


    public WebBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webHistory = new List<String>();
        webHistory_Index = 0;
        checkHistory = false;

    }
```

Back Button the one i'm testing currently

```
 private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String backPage = webHistory.ElementAt(webHistory.Count-1);
         webNavigate(backPage);
    }
```

Button Navigation Methods

```
 private void updateNavigation()
    {
        if (webHistory_Index == 0)
        {
            this.backButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.backButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        if (webHistory_Index < webHistory.Count)
        {
            this.forwardButton.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            this.forwardButton.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void navigatedPages(string urlbartext)
    {

        addressText = urlBar.Text;
        urlbartext = "http://" + addressText;
        webHistory.Add(urlbartext);
        if (!checkHistory)
    {
        if (webHistory_Index < webHistory.Count)
        {
            webHistory.RemoveRange(webHistory_Index, webHistory.Count - webHistory_Index);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(urlbartext + "   -    " + urlBar.SelectedText);
        webHistory_Index += 1;
        updateNavigation();
    }
    checkHistory = false;
    System.Console.WriteLine(webHistory.Count.ToString());
}
```

Web Browser Navigate method.

```
 private void webNavigate(string urlbartext )
    {
        addressText = urlBar.Text;
        urlbartext = "http://" + addressText;
        urlList.Add(urlbartext);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlbartext);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream pageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pageStream, Encoding.Default);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        webDisplay.Text = s;

        reader.Dispose();
        pageStream.Dispose();
        response.Close();

    }
```

When I click the back button the current page is still displayed and no errors given.Where am I going wrong?

TEST edit

```
 List<String> webHistory;
    int curIndex = -1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webHistory = new List<string>();
    }

    private void gotoUrl(string curUrl)
    {
        curUrl = "http://" + curUrl;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(curUrl);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream pageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pageStream, Encoding.Default);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        webDisplay.Text = s;
        reader.Dispose();
        pageStream.Dispose();
        response.Close();
    }


    private void addUrl(string curUrl)
    {

        if (webHistory.Count > 0 && webHistory.Count - 1 > curIndex) webHistory.RemoveRange(curIndex, webHistory.Count - curIndex - 1);
        webHistory.Add(curUrl);
        curIndex = webHistory.Count - 1;

        gotoUrl(curUrl);
    }

    private void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (curIndex - 1 >= 0)
        {

            curIndex = curIndex - 1;
            gotoUrl(webHistory[curIndex]);
        }
    }

    private void forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (curIndex + 1 <= webHistory.Count - 1)
        {

            curIndex = curIndex + 1;
            gotoUrl(webHistory[curIndex]);
        }
    }

    private void navigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addUrl(urlText.Text);
    }
```

Comment: First of all (and just to make sure): you cannot rely on the in-built WebBrowser, don't you? Second thing: with webHistory you want just to store the last visited pages and retrieve them by clicking on the back/forward buttons? Because you seem to be complicating things too much.

Comment: @varocarbas Yes I am not supposed to use the webBrowser class. And yes that is precisely what I want to do with webHistory.

Comment: There you have some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few problems in your code. But I think that the main problem is the lack of clarity regarding the main structure of the code. Here you have a small code performing the main actions you want that I hope that will help you to redo your code on different premises:

```
List<String> webHistory;
int curIndex = -1;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webHistory = new List<string>();
}

private void gotoUrl(string curUrl)
{
    //display the url in the browser
}


private void addUrl(string curUrl)
{
    //Add a new Url
    if (webHistory.Count > 0 && webHistory.Count - 1 > curIndex) webHistory.RemoveRange(curIndex, webHistory.Count - curIndex - 1);
    webHistory.Add(curUrl);
    curIndex = webHistory.Count - 1;

    gotoUrl(curUrl);
}


private void Previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (curIndex - 1 >= 0)
    {
        //Previous URL
        curIndex = curIndex - 1;
        gotoUrl(webHistory[curIndex]);
    }
}

private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (curIndex + 1 <= webHistory.Count - 1)
    {
        //Next URL
        curIndex = curIndex + 1;
        gotoUrl(webHistory[curIndex]);
    }
}

private void Navigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Simulate the user input by introducing new URLs
    addUrl("");
}
```

Just put three buttons on a new form: `Navigate`, `Previous` and `Next` (and associate the corresponding `Click Events`). This code delivers the behaviour you want in a much clearer (and accurate) way. I haven't tested it too much, but in principle should work fine in any situation. In any case, my intention is helping you to see the problems with your approach such that you can redo it from scratch, not delivering a working code for you to use it blindly.

Comment: So I built a quick form to try and test the code, however I get a nullreferenceexeption error on the addurl method. Specifically at this "curIndex" saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." what could be the problem?

Comment: @user2268970 !? (I am starting to half-regret having written this code... I was expecting you to have an adequate knowledge). Logically you are not copying my code because this error is triggered by a not-defined variable and, as you can see, curIndex is defined globally....

Comment: @user2268970 Open a new project, put 3 buttons on it (with the aforementioned names), click once on each of these buttons (3 methods will be generated with the names I am including above; put inside each method the corresponding code); click once on the form, a new method will be created (write Form1_Load contents inside it); ignore the public Form1() in my code (should have been automatically generated in yours) and write the remaining bits inside the class (by default, called Form1), including the heading List<String> webHistory; and int curIndex = -1;

Comment: @Varocrabas I had declared it globally but had made the mistake of having duplicate Forms however with that fix the navigation still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2268970 (sorry if I sounded a bit rude... but bear in mind the point of help: I hope that you maximise this information as intended) Please, tell me what you are doing or show me your code; I have tested it and should work without any problem.

Comment: @varocrabas Yes and I am trying to learn from your example. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: I have confirmed with breakpoints that the loop is working but the browser just wont navigate to the page when I press the back button. It just displays the current page.

Comment: @user2268970 Please, tell me what you are doing, step by step or show me what you are doing. Now I am on something else will be back. My nicks is varocarbas (I hope that you will pay more attention to the code)

Comment: I edited the OP under the TEST edit with your code. I built a simple web browser form and used your code to. So far the browser works fine I can load the pages but I can't go back to the previous visited pages. I haven't added anything to your code apart from adding my HTTP request methods which is how I load the pages. Please have a look when you can.

Comment: @user2268970 I will take a look at it right now. BTW, you cannot edit other's code; your correction was rejected by all the reviewers except "Nit" who I am not sure why accepted something completely against the SO rules. If you want to change something, ask me via comments.

Comment: @nit why have you accepted a completely wrong edition of my code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to do that I realised too late.

Comment: @user2268970 No problem. I have edited your code to make it work (you were overwriting the Url), it wasn't a revenge :) just a quick way to let you know about the problem. You cannot edit the code of others unless clear errors or having his permission (I guess that I have yours).